# Any drawbacks to SVN branch model: branch -> next-branch, abandoning trunk?

Tags: svn, branch

We have a release model which to keep things simple we'll say is 1 per month. So, we typically go:

```
Jan -> trunk
       trunk -> Feb
       trunk <- Feb
Mar <- trunk 
Mar -> trunk
       etc
```

We are considering just abandoning trunk, giving a model more like:

```
trunk -> Jan
  Jan -> Feb
  Feb -> Mar
  Mar -> Apr
  etc
```

We would never merge back to trunk.  While work takes place on Feb branch, any urgent fixes take place on Jan branch, and are merged down to Feb's codebase.

This seems to offer plenty upside, including far, far fewer merges.  Anyone spot obvious flaws/downsides, ideally from experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for other readers: approach worked fine after several months and several releases; benefits we'd hoped for all materialised, no downsides emerged. Consensus in the team was that it was a better model.

Answer (score 5):

> This seems to offer plenty upside

Can't see *any*, but can detect at least one headache

> including far, far fewer merges

Wrong. Forward-porting of patches in both workflows has **the same amount** of merges

**Resume**:

All URLS in Subversion have equal rights, using path /trunk as mainline is just convenion, which you can ignore. But don't forget about sidebacks - instead of single `svn up` to some older than current month revision you'll have `svn switch & svn up` (and identify URL of this revision before switch - add log to list also)

Comment: Maybe my explanation is poor/missing info. Jan merged to trunk, then create Feb branch, gives us 1 merge. Jan -> new Feb branch has zero merges. Jan is "live" only for one month, then we release Feb. So, we only ever merge in that direction, and would never have a situation where a Feb branch change is required on Jan. We might commit an emergency fix to Jan, and that's easy to merge down to Feb.

Comment: upvote for welcome discussion btw, I am keen to bounce ideas about on this

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you branch too early and are trying to abandon that early branching, but are not aware of it.

In a normal trunk-based workflow, you'd branch of "Jan" as soon as "Jan" is released. Then you continue to work on the trunk, and branch of "Feb" as "Feb" is released. In other words: **In a trunk model, you defer branching to the release point**. When you find yourself merging anything but feature branches or hotfixes back to your trunk, the workflow is broken. Planning considerable work on a release branch is wrong. The trunk and feature branches are for bread-and-butter work; the release branches are for emergencies.

Your new model is good, but you can keep established naming conventions with:

```
 trunk
 trunk -> Jan   /* Release */
 trunk <- Jan   /* Hotfix */
 trunk -> Feb
 trunk -> Mar
 trunk -> Apr
```

Note that this is topologically equivalent to the no-trunk model:

```
trunk                     Jan
 +----------- Jan          +------------   
 +------- Feb  |       Feb +--------   |
 +--- Mar  |   |       Mar +----   |   |
 |     |   |   |       Apr |   |   |   |
 |     |   |   |           |   |   |   |
trunk Mar Feb Jan         Apr Mar Feb Jan
```

However, in the no-trunk model, you are constantly renaming the vertical path that's named "trunk" in the trunk model. Since everyone is working on trunk most of the time, the naming gets in your way through a lot of switches, like LazyBadger already stated.

While the cost of an `svn switch` is certainly not high, the cost of a forgotten `svn switch` is. At some point, someone will accidentally work on `Mar` after returning from a vacation when `Apr` is the current branch. Then you'll have to detect that issue (QA), merge the code into `Apr` and revert in `Mar`. When usual work is done on `trunk`, the problem doesn't occur, because `trunk` is always a good point for new work.

Comment: I see what you mean; instead of work on branch, and use trunk as a merge point for its own sake, do all work on trunk - and use branches such as Jan, Feb, etc, purely for any subsequent fix work (and with no fixes needed, they're pretty much just tags).  That sounds a valid approach, certainly, but being devil's advocatey I don't see it being intrinsically "better" than Jan branch -> Feb branch -> Mar branch etc?

Comment: upvote for welcome discussion btw, I am keen to bounce ideas about on this

Comment: @Brian: It's better through less name switching. Updated answer to show the difference.